# Why do I get a DisjunctionsNotSupportedException when doing a SOQL query on Custom Metadata?

Tags: soql, exception, custom-metadata

I'm performing this query against a Custom Metadata object:

```
SELECT Call_Center_Display_Script__c
FROM VDN_Mapping__mdt 
WHERE VDN__c = '99999' OR DNIS__c = '123456786' 
LIMIT 1
```

But I'm getting this error from Salesforce:

> An error has occurred in the following section: [Exception, DisjunctionsNotSupportedException_desc]. Salesforce.com has been notified of this error.

Why does this occur and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Custom Metadata supports a limited SOQL syntax, and "OR" statements are not supported. From [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custommetadatatypes_limitations.htm&language=en_US):

> Custom metadata types support the following SOQL query syntax.

```
SELECT fieldList [...]
FROM objectType
    [USING SCOPE filterScope]
[WHERE conditionExpression]
[ORDER BY field {ASC|DESC} [NULLS {FIRST|LAST}] ]
```

> - The fieldList can include only non-relationship fields.
> - FROM can include only one object.
> - You can’t use COUNT with custom metadata types.
> - You can use the following operators.
>
>   - IN and NOT IN
>   - =, >, >=, <, <=, and !=
>   - LIKE, including wild cards
>   - AND
> - You can use ORDER BY, ASC, and DESC with multiple fields.

Notice that "OR" is not supported. Apparently that's called a "Disjunction"

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a known issue that is preventing this from working correctly.

[SOQL on metadata type records does not work properly when using LIKE in OR relationship](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=soql-on-metadata-type-records-does-not-work-properly-when-using-like-in-or-relationship&Id=a1p3A000001FT4J)